# How do I generate appropriate group-level coefficients and standard errors for my regression?

Tags: mean, regression-coefficients, standard-error

I ran a mixed logistic model testing the influence of group (two-level) on a binary outcome, and I want to report the group estimates and their SEs in graph. However, I can think of two ways of doing this that yield different estimates. If just compute estimates and SEs for each group separately I get different estimates and SEs than I would if I run models on the full data set and alternate which group I code as the baseline group (e.g., "0") and obtain the intercepts and SEs (i.e.,baseline group's estimate/SE).

So, to be clear, in the first approach I would do this like so in R (note this is just for illustration; my question is more conceptual rather than an R-programming question):

```
tilDF2<-subset(tilDF, Condition == "0")
modela<-glmer(Acc ~ 1 + (1|ID), data= tilDF2, family = binomial(logit))
summary(modela)

tilDF2<-subset(tilDF, Condition == "1")
modela<-glmer(Acc ~ 1 + (1|ID), data= tilDF2, family = binomial(logit))
summary(modela)
```

And in the second approach I would do this:

```
tilDF2<- 0*(tilDF$Acc==-0.5) + 1*(tilDF$Acc==0.5)
```

where I am contrast coding the conditions so that one condition is baseline

```
modela<-glmer(Acc ~ Condition + (1|ID), data= tilDF2, family = binomial(logit))
summary(modela)
```

And then doing the same for the other condition:

```
tilDF2<- 1*(tilDF$Acc==-0.5) + 0*(tilDF$Acc==0.5)
modela<-glmer(Acc ~ Condition + (1|ID), data= tilDF2, family = binomial(logit))
summary(modela)
```

I think the latter approach is more precise/accurate because it uses all the data and provides the baseline condition's predicted mean, controlling for the effect of condition. But the former approach seems to be more typical when graphing means. Any suggestion about whether one of these is more correct than the other?